# Include google maps libraries through default_head_blocks.xml

Tags: magento2, xml, google-map

When trying to implement the google maps API script in `default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&libraries=places" src_type="url"/>
```

it doesn't load the google maps script. But when I tried to replace the & with "&amp;" I get the following error:

> 1 exception(s):
>       Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 503: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php on line 493
>
> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 503: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php on line 493
>
> ```
> #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\DLB...', 493, Array)
> #1 vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(493): simplexml_load_string('<layouts xmlns:...', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
> #2 vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(716): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_loadXmlString('<layouts xmlns:...')
> #3 vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(633): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_loadFileLayoutUpdatesXml()
> #4 var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor.php(232): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()
> #5 vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(527): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()
> #6 vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(506): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
> #7 vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(434): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_merge('default')
> #8 var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
> #9 vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
> #10 vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
> #11 vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
> #12 vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
> #13 vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(227): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild()
> #14 vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #15 vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #16 vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
> #17 vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
> #18 vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #19 vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #20 vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
> #21 vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #22 vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #23 var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
> #24 vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #25 vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
> #26 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
> ```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replace src attribute to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&amp;amp;amp;libraries=places
```

It is work for me fine.

Comment: Replacing a `&` with `&amp;` should work. Probably Magento is doing some preprocessing, so it needs `&amp;amp;`? The third `amp;` in this answer is to keep `&amp;` in the final output to have the ampersand escaped properly inside the `src` attribute